# how to instance a php class inside php extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

how to instance a php class inside php extension!

here is my codes:

```
zval *obj;
MAKE_STD_ZVAL(obj);
zend_class_entry *foo_ce;
if( zend_hash_find( EG(class_table), "foo", sizeof("foo"), (void **)&foo_ce ) == SUCCESS ){
        printf("get foo success\n");
        object_init_ex(obj, foo_ce);    
} else {
        printf("get class failed\n");
}
printf("here\n");
```

but i got `Segmentation fault` when it goes to `object_init_ex` Snippet!

gdb info like this below:

```
\#0  0x0000000000925038 in zend_hash_apply_deleter (ht=0xfac750, p=0x120b980) at /root/php-5.5.38/Zend/zend_hash.c:619
\#1  0x00000000009257b2 in zend_hash_reverse_apply (ht=0xfac750, apply_func=0x8fe67f <clean_non_persistent_class>) at /root/php-5.5.38/Zend/zend_hash.c:804
\#2  0x00000000008fec25 in shutdown_executor () at /root/php-5.5.38/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:300
\#3  0x000000000091297d in zend_deactivate () at /root/php-5.5.38/Zend/zend.c:946
\#4  0x000000000088c26f in php_request_shutdown (dummy=0x0) at /root/php-5.5.38/main/main.c:1813
\#5  0x00000000009bc433 in do_cli (argc=2, argv=0xfabb10) at /root/php-5.5.38/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1177
\#6  0x00000000009bcabb in main (argc=2, argv=0xfabb10) at /root/php-5.5.38/sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1378
```

Comment: did you check if `obj` is pointing to valid memory?

Comment: Please provide more context, no error obvious to me here

Comment: I post my all codes up to github.com/longmon/php-ioc.git,

Answer (score 0):

I found a another way using `zend_lookup_class` to find a php class and instance it;

```
zend_class_entry **class_ce, *old_scope;
zval *retval_ptr;
zend_lookup_class( name, strlen(name), &class_ce TSRMLS_CC )；
object_init_ex(return_value, *class_ce);
```

then return_value is an object now!